# How can my macro take a variable instead of an unquoted list?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm building an alphametic solver, and I'd like to make a macro that substitutes numbers into a symbol template.

Here is a self-contained example:

```
(defparameter *symbol-positions* '(#\H #\T #\S #\R #\A #\U #\E #\O #\W #\N))

(defmacro word-to-number (symbols lst)
  `(tonumber (list ,@(loop for symbol in symbols
                           when (not (eql symbol #\ ))
                             collect `(nth ,(position symbol *symbol-positions*) ,lst )))))

(defparameter num '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
(defparameter east '(#\  #\E #\A #\S #\T))
```

The following call works:

```
(word-to-number (#\  #\E #\A #\S #\T) num)
```

But this one doesn't:

```
(word-to-number east num) ;=> The value EAST is not of type LIST
```

Is there a way I can modify the macro to take a variable for the SYMBOLS parameter? `,symbols` doesn't work, and neither does `` `(,@symbols) ``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
(word-to-number east num)
```

The macro expander gets called with the arguments being `east` and `num`. They won't be lists and number for you macro. Only for the resulting code will they be evaluated in a contex which yields values.

A macro is syntax transformation. eg.

```
(cond (p1 c1)
      (p2 c2)
      (t a))

; ==

(if p1
    c1
    (if p2 
        c2
        a))
```

It is regardless if `p1` is `(< a b)` or `my-boolean-value`. A macro just places the expressions there without having to know what `a`, `b` or `my-boolean-value` is.

So tell me.. How should the expansion look with `(word-to-number east num)`? Perhaps it shouldn't be a macro at all? eg.

```
(defun word-to-number (symbols lst)
  (tonumber (loop :for symbol :in symbols
                  :when (not (eql symbol #\ ))
                  :collect (nth (position symbol *symbol-positions*) lst))))
```

**UPDATE**

```
(defmacro word-to-number (symbols lst)
  `(tonumber (loop :for symbol :in ,symbols
                   :with clst := ,lst
                   :when (not (eql symbol #\ ))
                   :collect (nth (position symbol *symbol-positions*) clst))))
```

You might notice that I'm storing `lst` in a variable `clst` and I do it after evaluating `symbols`. The reason is that when you expect arguments to be evaluated you expect them to be evaluated in order and only once unless repeated evaluation is a feature of the macro like `loop` does. Eg. this should only print "Oh, happy day" once:

```
(word-to-number (progn (princ "Oh") east) (progn (princ ", happy day!") num))
```

Comment: Can I rewrite my macro to insert `east` as a symbol where `symbols` is now? The `num` substitution works.

Comment: You mean by returning the same code as my function has with `symbols` and `lst` replaced with their expressions? Shure, but you won't gain anything by it. Usually you do macros to delay evaluation of arguments so that you can abtract on code patterns.

Comment: I would like it if you could show me how to do that. Not because I will use it, but because it will help me understand the difference between how backticks work in functions and macros.

Comment: @GustavBertram backticks doesn't behave differently in functions and macros. A macro gets its macro function called with code (aka list structure) as arguments. The result is expected to be code ni data representation and the lisp system just replaces the macro call with the resulting code before running and often at function creation time. In fact you can make a function that does your macro job and call it from the macro with the same arguments. Easy to test `(word-to-number-impl 'east 'num)`